# Non out-of-the-box chart in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

We have a particular chart that we like using. I saw it in a book by Stephen Few:

[image]

The blue series is actually a line chart with markers: the markers have been expanded and the line has been deleted.

So it is not an out-of-the-box Excel chart but rather a bit of a hack.

What I don't seem to be able to do is spin it on it's side. So if I draw in the second series this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'm happy either just hacking the chart wizards or using a vba solution.

Comment: I spent a little time on this, but since it's a chart you can't simply manipulate it like you do with other shapes. I think the real question here is how to get the scatter plot to plot in that direction.

Comment: @Raystafarian I agree - that is the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this type of chart you need three columns of data, plotted on two axis, and build the chart in stages.

First, your data should look like this:

[image]

Next, select A1:B4 and Insert and Stacked Bar Chart to get this:

[image]

Now, select C1:D4 and Copy, then select your chart and Paste Special (add cells as New Series; Values in Columns; Series Names in First Row) to get this:

[image]

Excel just changed your chart type to a simple Bar Chart, but you still want a Stacked Bar Chart. So right click in the chart and Change Chart Type to Stacked Bar.

[image]

You'll notice that the scale of your primary axis is not showing what you need. In order to solve this, we'll move the two "Prev" columns to the Secondary Axis.

So, show the Format ribbon and in the upper left corner drop down menu select "Series PrevMthInvis", then click the Format Selection button underneath the drop down. In the Format dialog under Series Options, choose Secondary Axis. Then under Fill, select No Fill.

[image]

Back to the Ribbon and select "Series PrevMth" and Format Selection again. Select Secondary Axis, and change the Fill color to your desired value. Finally change the Gap Width to 50%.

[image]

At least in my Excel chart, the series are not in the correct order. You want the "PrevMth" series to be stacked on top of "PrevMthInvis", so right click on the chart and choose Select Data, then move the series to be ordered Mth, PrevMthInvis, then PrevMth.

[image]
[image]

The final clean up involves right clicking the secondary axis (the upper horizontal axis) and making sure the scale, min, and max matches the primary axis, then set Major and Minor Tick Marks and the Axis Labels to "None". Lastly, select "PrevMthInvis" in the legend and delete it.

[image]

You can change the width of your blue "bar" by changing the "PrevMth" value to 0.5 or whatever is best for you. Good luck!

Comment: lovely hack - appreciated